# Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Invalid Value [400] when trying to clear calendar

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

When I try to clear a specific calendar by id it gives me this error:

```
Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid Value [400]
Errors [
    Message[Invalid Value] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]
]
'
```

My code:

```
var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

service.Calendars.Clear("mycalendarid").Execute();
//service.Calendars.Clear("primary").Execute();

var ev = new Event();
EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
start.DateTime = new DateTime(2020, 8, 11, 8, 0, 0);

EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();
end.DateTime = new DateTime(2020, 8, 11, 9, 10, 0);
            

ev.Start = start;
ev.End = end;
ev.Summary = "3y MA";
ev.Description = "Lektier: blablabla \nblabla bla \n \nNote:\nBla Bla";

var calendarId = "mycalendarid";
Event recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(ev, calendarId).Execute();
Console.WriteLine("Event created: %s\n", ev.HtmlLink);
```

I can add an event to the right calendar but when I try to clear the same calendar I get the error. I can clear the primary calendar if I set the calendar id to primary but that is not the calendar I want to clear.

Comment: are you the owner of that calendar?

Comment: Yeah, I made it for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The method `Calendars: clear` only works for primary calendars

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear):

> Clears a primary calendar. This operation deletes all events associated with the primary calendar of an account.

If you create a test calendar that is not your priamry calendar (that is a `@group.calendar.google.com` calendar) and try to clear it, you will receive

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

**Workaround**

For testing purposes create a test user and test `Calendars: clear` on the primary calendar of the test user.